# node expressJwt unless specify id route

Tags: node.js, regex, express, express-jwt

We are using the expressJwt library and I want to be able to exclude the `GET` for the following route `api/items/:id` but not include any routes that look like `api/items/:id/special-action`.

So far, I've only been able to exclude all routes that have the `:id`.

Below is how we've achieved excluding `GET` routes that have `:id`.

```
this.app.use(expressJwt({ secret: secrets.JWT }).unless({
  path: [
    ...
    { url: /\/api\/items\/(.)/, methods: ['GET'] },
    ...
  ]
});
```

I've tried `{ url: /\/api\/items\/(.)\//, methods: ['GET'] }` but it then does not match to any routes and so no routes with `:id` get excluded.

There's something off in the way I'm using the regex, but I'm having a hard time seeing it.  Do I need to change the `(.)` to not be a match all?  I imagine it might be matching the trailing slashes

Comment: Works great.  Thank you!

Comment: Didn't see it, mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\/api\/items\/([^\/]*)$/
```

The `[^\/]*` negated character class matches 0 or more chars other than `/` and the `^` / `$` anchors make sure the pattern will be tried against the whole string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPmBlS/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `\/api\/items\/` - matches  a literal `/api/items/` substring
- `([^\/]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `/`.
- `$` - end of string anchor.
  Note that in case you want to make sure the `[^\/]*` has no `/` after, add a `$` end of string anchor at the end.

Comment: I apologize, I spoke prematurely on this working. I thought the next issue I was seeing was something different. It appears that express jwt is still matching everything.  `/api/items/:id/special-action` is still not running through expressjwt

Comment: Try adding anchors. `/^\/api\/items\/([^\/]*)$/`

Comment: *sigh... I thought I had done that haha.  It works now. thank you